# getElementsByTagName() applying two times don't work

Tags: javascript

```
<ul id="nav">
    Favorite beverages :
    <li> Tea </li>
    <li> Coffee </li>
    <li> Milk </li>
</ul>
```

I want total number of 'li' from 'ul'

```
Method 1 : It doesn't work

var val =  document.getElementsByTagName("ul").getElementsByTagName("li");
console.log(val.length);

Method 2 : It works

var val =  document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("li");
console.log(val.length);
```

Why Method 1 don't work?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("ul")`returns array of elements. So,  `getElementsByTagName` is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `document.getElementsByTagName("ul")`  returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

For your understanding:

`element.getElementsByTagName("li")` is valid method.

`elements.getElementsByTagName("li")` is not a valid method.

```js
var val = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
console.log(val.length);


var val = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("li");
console.log(val.length);
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  Favorite beverages :
  <li> Tea </li>
  <li> Coffee </li>
  <li> Milk </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit** to get the text in `ul` but not `li`

```js
var val = document.getElementById("nav").firstChild.wholeText;
console.log(val);
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  Favorite beverages :
  <li> Tea </li>
  <li> Coffee </li>
  <li> Milk </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Sankar Raj.  I have one additional question what to do if need to find of text in "ul" tag but not in "li". Example in above case how to find "Favorite beverages :"

Answer (score 1):

Please check the documentation of these method. Its clearly said

The [getElementsByTagName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)() method **returns a collection of all elements** in the document with the specified tag name, as a NodeList object.

The [getElementById](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)() method **returns the element that has the ID** attribute with the specified value.

So it should be

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")
```